# Print page as pdf selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, html

How can I print a webpage as a PDF with headers and footers so it looks like it has been printed from google chrome.

This is what I have tried so far using PhantomJS but it doesn't have the headers and footers.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium

def execute(script, args):
    driver.execute('executePhantomScript', {'script': script, 'args' : args })

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')

# hack while the python interface lags
driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')

driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')

# set page format
# inside the execution script, webpage is "this"
pageFormat = '''this.paperSize = {format: "A4", orientation: "portrait" };'''
execute(pageFormat, [])

# render current page
render = '''this.render("test.pdf")'''
execute(render, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `Selenium` `v4.1.3` by following `pyppeteer` examples.

You will need to be able to send commands to chromium and call [Page.printToPDF](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF) Devtools API as shown in the following snip:

```py
# ...
result = send_cmd(driver, "Page.printToPDF", params={
            'landscape': True
        ,'margin':{'top':'1cm', 'right':'1cm', 'bottom':'1cm', 'left':'1cm'}
        ,'format': 'A4'
        ,'displayHeaderFooter': True
        ,'headerTemplate': '<span style="font-size:8px; margin-left: 5px">Page 1 of 1</span>'
        ,'footerTemplate': f'<span style="font-size:8px; margin-left: 5px">Generated on {datetime.now().strftime("%-m/%-d/%Y at %H:%M")}</span>'
        ,'scale': 1.65
        ,'pageRanges': '1'
})

with open(out_path_full, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(base64.b64decode(result['data']))

# ...

def send_cmd(driver, cmd, params={}):
  response = driver.command_executor._request(
     'POST'
    ,f"{driver.command_executor._url}/session/{driver.session_id}/chromium/send_command_and_get_result"
    ,json.dumps({'cmd': cmd, 'params': params}))
  if response.get('status'): raise Exception(response.get('value'))
  return response.get('value')
```

I've included a full example in my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/Selenium2Pdf).

Comment: What `send_cmd` bro?

Comment: Its in my full example in Github but I'll add here for posterity.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. I got an error `'footerTemplate': f'<span style="font-size:8px; margin-left: 5px">Generated on {datetime.now().strftime("%-m/%-d/%Y at %H:%M")}</span>'
ValueError: Invalid format string` but I fixed that part `%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S`. Now I got another error `Exception: Invalid Command Method - {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json"` at this line `result = send_cmd(driver, "Page.printToPDF"`

Comment: Sorry, wrote the code on Linux. Please try my full example in Github (https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/Selenium2Pdf/blob/main/Selenium2Pdf.py). I just tested on Windows and it works fine.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: I have tested the code in the link and it is great. Is it possible to make the code take snapshots of the whole page not only the first shown part of the website? I mean to make it scroll down to load the full page. I tested on this link as an example https://maktoob.yahoo.com/?p=us

Comment: Yes you can change pages printed with the `printRanges` setting. Just comment it out to get all pages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great support. It is `pageRanges`.

Comment: I updated my Github example to show some more techniques and references to the Chromium settings. BTW - If you are looking for performance, consider puppeteer. It is measurably faster then selenium.

Comment: Do you have a youtube channel?

Comment: No. Just a OSS fan :)

Answer (score -2):

[pdfkit](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit) may help you out. It will render a PDF from an html page.